# Is this method for loading data in a C# application recommended?

Tags: c#, mysql, mvvm, dapper

**Goal**

I'd like to understand if this current method, of **loading data** and **inserting data** into a database I currently use is to be avoided?

**Code**

I drafted a simple application that loads data and inserts data, simple as that.

**Model**

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

**Database service**

```
public interface IDatabaseService
{
    List<Person> GetPeople();
    void InsertPerson(Person person);
}

public class DatabaseService : IDatabaseService
{
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("connection"))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM People;";
            var details = conn.Query<Person>(query);

            return details.ToList();
        }
    }

    public void InsertPerson(Person person)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("connection"))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO People (Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (@Firstname, @Lastname);";
            conn.Execute(query, new { @Firstname = person.Firstname, @Lastname = person.Lastname });
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    // Property to be loaded with records
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }


    // Properties to create new Person
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    // Contructor
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Create database service and assign it to the readonly property
        DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();
        _databaseService = databaseService;

        LoadData();

        InsertDataCommand = new RelayCommand(InsertData);
    }

    // Service
    private readonly DatabaseService _databaseService;

    // Load data method
    protected void LoadData()
    {
        if(People == null)
        {
            People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        }
        People.Clear();
        _databaseService.GetPeople().ForEach(record => People.Add(record));
    }

    // Command to add new Person
    public ICommand InsertDataCommand { get; }
    protected void InsertData(object param)
    {
        Person person = new Person()
        {
            Firstname = Firstname,
            Lastname = Lastname
        };
        _databaseService.InsertPerson(person);

        // Refresh
        LoadData();
    }
}
```

**Question**

In my view model, the way I clear the ObservableCollection and reload the data.. is this ok?

Comment: Entity Framework, Code First.

Comment: Meanwhile opening/closing the connection to each query may be not efficient unless they a pooled (connection string params setup).

Comment: Why Entity Framework just out of curiosity? I think using queries with dapper is relevantly easy in my opinion?

Comment: Looks like initially there was no sense to develop EF then.

Comment: I recommend having a backend between client and data storage

Comment: @Anders Can you expand on your comment please? :)

Comment: No need to use EF. Dapper is OK.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thank you!

Comment: The title to your question is too generic. Please follow the guidelines: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Repository` layer which would be between `Data` and `Service` layers. Never use `Service` directly to `Data` layer. The `Service` layer suppose to hold the business logic that would be applied on the `Repository` layer.  Each `Service` can work with one or more repositories, but each repository should only work with one entity.
Here is an example :

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    public List<Person> GetPeople() { /* Dapper code here */  }

    public void InsertPerson(Person person) { /* Dapper code here */  }
}

public class PersonService 
{
    private readonly PersonRepository _personRepo = new PersonRepository();
    
    public List<Person> GetPeople() 
    { 
        // if there is some business logic needed 
        // you can add it here 
        return _personRepo.GetPeople();
    }
    
    public List<Person> InsertPerson(Person person)
    { 
        // if there is some business logic needed 
        // you can add it here 
        _personRepo.InsertPerson(person);
    }   
}
```

Each `Repository` should validate the object against the entity requirements (e.g. database table).

Each `Service` should validate the object against the business logic requirements.

In your view model, class properties should be at the top of the class not in between, and sort them by private properties first, then public properties comes after.

This part :

```
 // Contructor
public MainViewModel()
{
    // Create database service and assign it to the readonly property
    DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();
    _databaseService = databaseService;

    LoadData();

    InsertDataCommand = new RelayCommand(InsertData);
}
   
// Load data method
protected void LoadData()
{
    if(People == null)
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }
    People.Clear();
    _databaseService.GetPeople().ForEach(record => People.Add(record));
}
```

can be simplified by this :

```
 // Contructor
public MainViewModel()
{
    _databaseService = new DatabaseService(); 
    LoadData();
    InsertDataCommand = new RelayCommand(InsertData); 
}

// Load data method
protected void LoadData()
{
    People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(_databaseService.GetPeople());
}
```

Comment: What is this pattern called? Using the Repository..

Comment: @Squirrel.98 it has no official design pattern name that I'm aware of, but it's known by Repository/Service pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The way you implemented it looks absolute fine to me.

I would initialized the ObservabaleCollection with object creation and make it as get-only property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

That avoids the risk of null reference exceptions or different collection objects.

Clearing and recreating all objects is the simple case. It works but has the down side that the selected person within the grid disapears when realoding the persons (however, that may be ok in your use case).

An more advanced way is to update exiting, remove deleted and insert new persons. That requires a lot more code (e.g. you have to implement a PersonVioewModel with property changed support) but has better user experience on the other hand.

Comment: I like your last comment - do you know any resources with an example of what you have described? I'd like to look into it.

Comment: You have just to synchronize the two lists instead of recreating them: If item is in target but not in source, remove it; If item is in target and source, update it; if item is in source but not in target, add it. Here is an explaination of PropertyChanged implementation if you are not familiar with it: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf-mvvm/

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

- `PersonId` (in `Person`) is IMHO not a great pattern. IMHO you shouldn't prefix a property name with its class name.
- `IDatabaseService` is far to generic a name. I'd use `PersonService` and use that class to handle all `Person`-related queries. Then you can have more generic names like `GetAll()` instead of `GetPeople()`.
- Use descriptive names. `details` as in  `var details = conn.Query<Person>(query);` is not the correct name.
- I don't find `InsertPerson` a great method name. To me it should be something like `Create` (along with `Edit` and `Delete` or `Remove`).
- Why do you do this:

  ```
    DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();
    _databaseService = databaseService;
  ```

  Why not simply do `_databaseService = new DatabaseService();`?

  (Also you should use Dependency Injection to inject such a service.)
- Don't put pointless comments all over the place. Comments should be rare and should only be used to explain why something is implemented the way it is. If you need the comment `// Load data method` it means your method name is not clear enough.

Comment: I understand your points - but overall the `.Clear()` then `.ForEach(...Add(record))` is that ok to use?

Comment: @Squirrel.98 It's been too long since I've done WPF, but to me iSR5's solution -- `new ObservableCollection<Person>(_databaseService.GetPeople());` -- seems better: one line, no `ForEach`.